# How to get the number of lines if the current times matches between two fields?

Tags: sql, sql-server

| ID | _From | _To | Code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 08:00 | 11:00 | 4002138 |
| 2 | 15:00 | 17:00 | 4002138 |

**Example 1**

```
select COUNT(ID) from GroupsTime where code='4002138' and
CAST(REPLACE(convert(nvarchar(5), cast(getdate() as time),120),':','') as integer) 
between CAST(REPLACE(convert(nvarchar(5), cast(_To as time),120),':','') as integer) and 
CAST(REPLACE(convert(nvarchar(5), cast(_From as time),120),':','') as integer)
```

**Example 2**

```
select COUNT(*) from GroupsTime where code='4002138' 
and (_From>convert(time,getdate(),120) or _To<convert(time,getdate(),120))
```

Please tell me where am i wrong?

Comment: I'm a bit lost.  You have no date in the data and yet the title says that you want to match the date.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff sorry. corrected.

Comment: In your second attempt, you have your `>` and `<` the wrong way round. No time can be `< 08:00` and `> 11:00`. It's like asking for a number larger than 4 and less than 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are referring to the current *time*, then you can use:

```
where convert(time, getdate()) >= _from and
      convert(time, getdate()) <= _to
```

Comment: select * from GroupsTime where code='4002138' 
and (convert(time, getdate()) >= _from and
      convert(time, getdate()) <= _to)

Comment: still returns 0 row

Comment: @MubinjonMuinov . . . It depends what the time is on the computer you are using.

Comment: Yes. I keep track of my time, now I have 15:28.

Comment: The code should output 1 line since there are now matches on the second line.

Comment: "Works on my machine" @MubinjonMuinov . [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=7e586847e58d47e994eef82227657e10)

Comment: Very strange. The code doesn't work for me.

Comment: I suspect the time you think it is, isn't the time your server thinks it is, @MubinjonMuinov . `GETDATE()` returns the time local to the **host**, not *your* local time. If you're using an Azure host, for example, these all run in UTC so `GETDATE()` would return `13:40`~ right now.

Comment: @Larnu. But. it is logical that your code is correct.

Comment: I don't understand your comment, @MubinjonMuinov .

Comment: Your code is correct, but it works for me.

Comment: *"Your code is correct, but it works for me."* it's not *my* code it's Gordon's, but if it works for you too, then you should accept the answer as the solution, @MubinjonMuinov , to let people know the answer was helpful and solved your problem.

Comment: I am using sql server 2008r2, or is this why it doesn't work?

Comment: SQL Server 2008R2 has nothing to do with it, @MubinjonMuinov ; `time` was added in SQL Server 2008. The only problem with it is that it's completely unsupported (has been for over 2 years). But you *[just said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68773039/how-to-get-the-number-of-lines-if-the-current-times-matches-between-two-fields/68773062?noredirect=1#comment121541388_68773062)* it's working for you. Which is it..?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help. In fact, the code works, it turns out I work remotely, but I just noticed that my time is different from the server time, that's why the code didn't work all this time.

Comment: @Larnu you right. "GETDATE() returns the time local to the host"...